# Handling two different types of returns in one call (File(Blob) or JSON) Typscript

Tags: angular, typescript, asp.net-core, httprequest, httpresponse

This is kind of a confusing question, but hopefully someone can help.

Basically I am calling an API from a service in Angular 11 that can return one of two things.

1. If the API processes the uploaded file correctly, it returns a new File to the user.
2. If the API doesn't process the uploaded file correctly, it returns JSON to the user

How do I write a request that can handle either the response being a File or the response being JSON? I am having a ton of trouble with it.

Thanks in advance.

(My current request in my service)

```
return this._http.post(this.baseUrl, formData, {observe: 'response', responseType: 'blob'});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should return with bad request from the server and you can use rxjs operators to solve this problem. Rxjs operators are used in *pipe()* function.

You can handle the bad request with *catchError()* operator https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/error_handling/catch

In *catchError()* operator you should return with observable. In this example I just return with null value wrapped in observable.

```
return this._http.post(this.baseUrl, formData, {observe: 'response', responseType: 'blob'}).pipe(
  catchError((response: any) => {
    // you can write code here

    // you should return with observable
    return of(null);
  }),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo have to specify both types in the return type section of the method as shown below:

```cs
public apiCall(YourParameters): TypeA | TypeB {
  // your code
}
```